# update-grub doesn't detects my XP instalation

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows-xp

I installed Windows XP, and I was missing GRUB. Booted to Ubuntu with a GRUB recovery disc.(I doesn't know it's name) Then, I ran `sudo update-grub` and this is the output:

> > sebastian@sebastian-desktop:~$ sudo update-grub
>
> Generating grub.cfg ...
>
> Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-16-generic-pae
>
> Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-16-generic-pae
>
> Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
>
> Found Windows Vista (loader) on /dev/sda1
>
> done
>
> sebastian@sebastian-desktop:~$

Where is my Windows XP?
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin and GRUB 1.99

Comment: Fixed problem by adding Windows XP to Vista loader, because Vista loader was in my GRUB! :)

Comment: Than you must answer your question, and after some time you will be able to accept it. And please remove "SOLVED!" from title of your question.